# Get the list of functions in the current script

Tags: python, function

I have a fairly simple script and I need to get the names of the functions and their arguments in the same script. Only solutions I can find is to get the methods of an object or the functions in a module. But not for a current script. 
So for the example in the script below I need to get:
(foo, a,b ) and (bar, c, d)

```
def foo(a,b):
  pass

def bar(c,d):
  pass

this = gimmeFunctionsAndTheirArgNames()
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: Have you tried `filter(callable, locals().values())`?

Comment: [What purpose does this serve?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: It's for automatic gui creation. When new functions are added, the gui updates itself automatically.

Comment: why this negative attitude? he asked a simple legit question. how can you get the name of functions in files.

Comment: @Elisha: It *looks* like a legit question, but it's actually only *very* rarely useful.

Answer (score 1):

you can get list of functions in the locals scope this way:

```
>>> filter(callable, locals().values())
[<function bar at 0x01F337B0>, <function foo at 0x01F33430>]
```

or, I you want a name to functinon dictionary you can do:

```
>>> {f.func_name:f for f in filter(callable,locals().values())}
{'foo': <function foo at 0x01F33430>, 'bar': <function bar at 0x01F337B0>}
```